# SQL subqueries with 'exists' clause and multiple tables

Tags: sql, subquery, exists

*sorry, not enough reputation to post images*. I have 3 SQL tables:

x1: {'a':1,2,3,4,5},

x2: {'c':1,1,1,2,2,3,3, 'd':1,3,5,1,3,1,1},

x3: {'b':1,3,5}

---

The query is:

```
select a from x1 
where not exists (
  select * from x3
  where not exists (
    select *
    from x2
    where x1.a = x2.c and x3.b=x2.d
  )
)
```

---

The result from the following query is '**1**', but I can't understand what are the steps taken to get to that result.

What is being returned in which subquery?

Comment: Suggestion... Edit your existing post.  Your table samples of data are too generic.  Although we could give you explanation, having proper context is best.  If dealing with customers, orders, products, or similar, do so rather than us trying to guess why would this person even want such a strange query.  Might even be better way to do AND explain including optimization options to consider for your long-term solution.  BTW, Welcome to S/O.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain. Your query will fetch records from table a for which the result set of

[image]

is empty(ie is asserted by **not exists**)

Consider the data in the tables

[image]

The values in a are 1,2,3,45

Lets check for a=1

We got against a=1 with c=1 three records in Table x2

[image]

And for the 3 records all of the column d values are present in table x3. This means the output of the block will return empty for a=1 and therefore will be present in the final output.

Check for a=2, the possible values in d are 1 and 3 and as we got 5 in table x3  the query will return a non-empty result

Similarly for a=3 the inner query returns 3 and 5 from table x3

For a=45, as a doesnt exist in table x2,all of the records table x3 gets returned -> 1,3,5

Therefore the only a which satisfy the empty result set is a=1 which is the answer.